# What is the risk of specifying --verify 0 with blockchain_import?

Tags: blockchain-import

I have noticed that importing a blockchain snapshot file `blockchain.raw` speeds up dramatically when using `--verify 0`. The default value is `1` though. What is the downside, or risk, of **not verifying** blocks and transactions during import? Would this just result in an error when doing `rescan_bc` in simplewallet? Or is there anything else to be aware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, by not verifying, you're assuming the download is trusted. But there could be all sorts of bogus data in the `blockchain.raw`, if you have a man-in-the-middle attack during the download.

Personally, I only ever use `blockchain.raw` imports when I'm experimenting on very low power ARM devices, syncing up from scratch in nearly every case is significantly faster - and safer!

Comment: Would `monerod` detect invalid data? I just read a comment on [Slack](https://monero.slack.com/messages/monero/) about "consecutive valid block hashes". Wondering whether the daemon would error, or broadcast invalid data to incoming connections? I would guess the latter should not be possible, or else the network might get infected?

Comment: The import would break, even with --verify off

Comment: If you are importing a blockchain.raw that you generated yourself from a different instance, and that instance verified the blockchain as it arrived, then there is no risk in `--verify 0` because you've already verified.  For a blockchain obtained somewhere else, the only reliable thing to do is `--verify 1`